# 'package install failed' when create new project

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

The error in NPM, 'package install failed,

When I create new project in angular then use this command

> ng new project_name

Then it show me this error:

[image]

Comment: Please, include the error trace in the question so that it can be better answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every command generates a log file that store in your npm_cache than you have to delete this log file using this command

> npm cache clean --force

to delete cache in your npm_cache

after that install angular

> npm install -g @angular/latest

it's download the latest version of angular